# Getting a memory address instead of the object at that address

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, pointers, memory-management

I'm writing a program that contains an array with multiple objects inside it. Then, I take specific objects from that array and store their indexes (from array1) in another array as NSNumbers. Now, I'm trying to reference the objects from array1 later on in the project by pulling the indexes out of array2 in a table view, but I keep getting an error that suggests that I'm getting the objects' memory addresses instead of the object itself. Code to follow:

```
self.indexArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (Item *item in array1){
        if (item.ID == comparedItem.ID){
            NSUInteger num = [array1 indexOfObject:item];
            NSNumber *numval = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:num];
            [self.indexArray addObject:numval];
        }
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = (EditItemTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"quantityCell"];
int indexNum = [[self.indexArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row-1)] intValue];
NSString *descString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ - %@",[[array1 objectAtIndex:indexNum]desc1],[[array1 objectAtIndex:indexNum]desc2],indexNum];
return cell;
}
```

So I'm getting an error on the line: `int indexNum = [[self.indexArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row-1)] intValue];` that usually reads something like this: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'`. This is assuming I added 3 objects to the array before running the code above (hence the 0 .. 2). I'm assuming that 4294967295 is a memory address. Does anybody have any idea about how I can get the object itself instead?

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you log the value of indexPath or indexPath.row before that line of code?

Comment: `4294967295` is `-1` represented as an unsigned int32. In this context, it represents `indexPath.row-1 == -1` or `indexPath.row == 0`.

Comment: It looks like`indexPath.row` is 0, and subtracting 1 results in integer underflow.

Comment: IndexPath.row is giving me good data (0, 1,  2, based on the iteration). Logging something like `[self.indexArray objectAtIndex:2]` where I hardcode the objectAtIndex instead of referencing it using indexPath.row-1 is also giving me a valid answer.

Comment: Oh. Well it appears that I'm a complete idiot. Wow. I'm astonished at my own stupidity. Ian or Nobody, whoever posts their answer first will get a fancy green checkmark from me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`4294967295` is `-1` represented as an unsigned int32. In this context, it represents `indexPath.row-1 == -1` or `indexPath.row == 0`.

I'm not sure why you're subtracting `1` from your `indexPath.row`, but you should add some safety to check the bounds to make sure your array lookup won't be fetching an element that's out of bounds.

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) // do something special
```

or

```
[self.indexArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```